# Android: Resizing RGB_565 textures?

Tags: android, resize, rgb, textures

I've currently been trying to optimize my app with RGB_565 textures rather than RGBA_8888 textures. All is well except when I try to re-size these textures? Is there some hard coded reason why I can't simply make these textures smaller?

I'm trying to keep all my textures larger than necessary so I can scale down; thus being able to dynamically scale the textures for larger screens to have better image quality. This doesn't seem to work with RGB_565 or I'm missing something :-?.

- Should I just create a few different copies and dynamically LOAD the correct one rather than SCALE it? Thanks for any help you can offer!

[EDIT]
The whole point here is that I can't dynamically re-size/scale these textures once loaded into the app? They stretch like pulled from top right and bottom left of screen when I try to reduce their size even...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to do with the GL blend functions that can be used. Didn't get into it, simply re-sized them statically for now, but when I do get into it again I'll be sure to post the code!